# Pandas Rolling mean with GroupBy and Sort

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
f_period f_year f_month subject month year value
20140102 2014   1      a        1     2018 10
20140109 2014   1      a        1     2018 12
20140116 2014   1      a        1     2018 8
20140202 2014   2      a        1     2018 20
20140209 2014   2      a        1     2018 15
20140102 2014   1      b        1     2018 10
20140109 2014   1      b        1     2018 12
20140116 2014   1      b        1     2018 8
20140202 2014   2      b        1     2018 20
20140209 2014   2      b        1     2018 15
```

The `f_period` is the date when a forecast for a SKU (column `subject`) was made. The `month` and `year` column is the period for which the forecast was made. For example, the first row says that on `01/02/2018`, the model was forecasting to set `10` units of product `a` in month `1` of year`2018`.

I am trying to create a rolling average prediction by `subject`, by `month` for 2 `f_months`. The DataFrame should look like:

```
f_period f_year f_month subject month year value mnthly_avg rolling_2_avg
20140102 2014   1      a        1     2018 10    10         13
20140109 2014   1      a        1     2018 12    10         13
20140116 2014   1      a        1     2018 8     10         13
20140202 2014   2      a        1     2018 20    17.5       null
20140209 2014   2      a        1     2018 15    17.5       null
20140102 2014   1      b        1     2018 10    10         13
20140109 2014   1      b        1     2018 12    10         13
20140116 2014   1      b        1     2018 8     10         13
20140202 2014   2      b        1     2018 20    17.5       null
20140209 2014   2      b        1     2018 15    17.5       null
```

**Things I tried:**

I was able to get `mnthly_avg` by :

```
data_df['monthly_avg'] = data_df.groupby(['f_month', 'f_year', 'year', 'month', 'period', 'subject']).\
        value.transform('mean')
```

I tried getting the `rolling_2_avg` :

```
rolling_monthly_df = data_df[['f_year', 'f_month', 'subject', 'month', 'year', 'value', 'f_period']].\
            groupby(['f_year', 'f_month', 'subject', 'month', 'year']).value.mean().reset_index()

rolling_monthly_df['rolling_2_avg'] = rolling_monthly_df.groupby(['subject', 'month']).\
            value.rolling(2).mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

This gave me an unexpected output. I don't understand how it calculated the values for `rolling_2_avg`

How do I group by `subject` and `month` and then sort by `f_month` and then take the average of the next two-month average?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding it seems simpler than what you've done. What about this?

```
grp = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['subject', 'month', 'f_month'])['value'].sum())
grp['rolling'] = grp.rolling(window=2).mean()
grp
```

Output:

```
                          value rolling
subject     month   f_month         
a              1    1       30  NaN
               2            35  32.5
b              1    1       30  32.5
               2            35  32.5
```

Comment: I just switched `f_month` and `month`. That did the trick. You are right! I complicated it.

Comment: I would add that you should actually also sort by date before grouping to avoid issues : `df.sort_values(by='f_period').groupby(['subject', 'month', 'f_month'])['value'].sum().to_frame()`.

Plus, the `to_frame()` is an easier way to convert from series to dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I would be a bit careful with Josh's solution. If you want to group by the subject you can't use the rolling function like that as it will roll across subjects (i.e. it will eventually take the mean of a month from subject A and B, rather than giving a null which you might prefer).

An alternative can be to split the dataframe and run the rolling individually (I noticed that you want the nulls by the end of the dataframe, whereas you might wanna sort the dataframe before and after):

```
for unique_subject in df['subject'].unique():
    df_subject = df[df['subject'] == unique_subject]
    df_subject['rolling'] = df_subject['value'].rolling(window=2).mean()
    print(df_subject) # just to print, you may wanna concatenate these
```